# Datatables how to export a user's current datatable view data (including ordering) to another page

Tags: jquery, datatable

> Note: This question uses Datatables 1.11.50

I have a very large datatables table which is custom ordered by the end browser user. I need to achieve a concept whereby they can sort their datatable data on the browser page, for example ordering a payflow chart by age descending

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#example').DataTable({
dom: 'Bfrtip',
    buttons: [
        {
            text: 'View These rows on a Map'
             /* Do something here when the button is pressed to pass the
                currently displayed rows (only) primary id's (only) on 
                to another page to work with. */ 
        }
]
});
} );
```

```css
@import url("https://cdn.datatables.net/1.11.5/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css");
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script><script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.11.5/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/2.2.2/js/dataTables.buttons.min.js"></script>

<table id="example" class="display" style="width:100%">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Name</th>
                <th>Position</th>
                <th>Office</th>
                <th>Age</th>
                <th>Start date</th>
                <th>Salary</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td>Tiger Nixon</td>
                <td>System Architect</td>
                <td>Edinburgh</td>
                <td>61</td>
                <td>2011/04/25</td>
                <td>$320,800</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Garrett Winters</td>
                <td>Accountant</td>
                <td>Tokyo</td>
                <td>63</td>
                <td>2011/07/25</td>
                <td>$170,750</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Ashton Cox</td>
                <td>Junior Technical Author</td>
                <td>San Francisco</td>
                <td>66</td>
                <td>2009/01/12</td>
                <td>$86,000</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Cedric Kelly</td>
                <td>Senior Javascript Developer</td>
                <td>Edinburgh</td>
                <td>22</td>
                <td>2012/03/29</td>
                <td>$433,060</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Airi Satou</td>
                <td>Accountant</td>
                <td>Tokyo</td>
                <td>33</td>
                <td>2008/11/28</td>
                <td>$162,700</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Brielle Williamson</td>
                <td>Integration Specialist</td>
                <td>New York</td>
                <td>61</td>
                <td>2012/12/02</td>
                <td>$372,000</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Herrod Chandler</td>
                <td>Sales Assistant</td>
                <td>San Francisco</td>
                <td>59</td>
                <td>2012/08/06</td>
                <td>$137,500</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Rhona Davidson</td>
                <td>Integration Specialist</td>
                <td>Tokyo</td>
                <td>55</td>
                <td>2010/10/14</td>
                <td>$327,900</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Colleen Hurst</td>
                <td>Javascript Developer</td>
                <td>San Francisco</td>
                <td>39</td>
                <td>2009/09/15</td>
                <td>$205,500</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Sonya Frost</td>
                <td>Software Engineer</td>
                <td>Edinburgh</td>
                <td>23</td>
                <td>2008/12/13</td>
                <td>$103,600</td>
            </tr>
            </tbody>
            </table>
```

What I need to do is take the above example and order the:

- number of rows displayed (10/25/50/etc.)
- order of data; source data `id` points in a specific order
- ignore any data not on display to the user on the datatable

And somehow pass this data across to another page to use; the recieving page is a Leaflet map which will load the lat/long positions for each id value of the rows selected;

So; for example above -- lets sat view = 10 and order by `age` decending, from `Ashton Cox` (oldest) down to  `Cedric Kelly` **in that order** and then takes these id's (currently in hidden fields within the datatable) in that order and process them on leafletJS map to then output these and only these on a map location.

To be absolutely clear - the datatable itself is very large with 50+ fields and with many thousands of rows. All of these are from database data but the user needs to select certain rows; ie using search box to select certain types of rows and then order arrows to order these rows accordingly. *Then* this end result can be somehow passed across to another page that will load and populate a leaflet JS map with these data points.

---

I have looked at something like the ["Select" plugin for Datatables](https://datatables.net/extensions/select/integration) but can't see a way to grab and export the selected data.

I have no ideas at all and I can't find any reference points on the internet to begin exploring this;

How can I "export" this current view as a JSON encode or whatever format so that someone can press a Datatables button and complete the above request?

Any advice on this greatly appreciated.

Cheers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Note: this solution uses Datatables 1.11.50

The neatest working solution was to add a button (using Datatables Buttons plugin [Here](https://datatables.net/extensions/buttons/) ) that automatically took the required data and submitted it to the hardcoded destination.

There are two aspects to the data being  collected from the datatables:

- Export the raw data
- Export the order the data is in.

The first part of exporting the data can be achieved by using Datatables Select extension ([Here](https://datatables.net/extensions/select/)) and native datatable API functionality can catch the [current ordering](https://datatables.net/reference/api/order()) using `table.order()`.

The second part is required as the default datatables the rows can be ordered by the column values `ascending` or `descending`.

This presents two objects/arrays (array's are types of objects in Javascript) that with some processing work can be exported as vars either as GET values on a URL or as  POST values in an AJAX request.

Below is the code that selects the whole current page view (and only the whole current page view) and then saves id numbers from within this data as well as ordering information (for why these id's are in this order).

Example code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    // set vars for saving data and ordering info.
    var saveData = [];
    var orderOfData = [];
    var tempvar = "";

    var t = $('#table').DataTable({
        buttons {[
          // button display text
          text: 'View These rows on a Map',

          // action to carry out clicking on this button
          action: function ( e, dt, node, config ) {
               // Clear any pre selected rows              
               if(dt.rows().length > 0 ) {
                  dt.rows({selected: true}).deselect();
               }
      
              // Select current page rows.         
              dt.rows({page: 'current'}).select();
              var RowobjectData = dt.rows( { selected: true } ).data();

              //set order by list from column headers.
              // this returns column number, needs to be turned into text (or id)
              var ordering = t.order();

              // Building ordering Text List.
              $.each(ordering, function(indexO, innerOrder) {
                    // Grab name reference for each column id.  
                    tempvar = $(t.column( innerOrder[0] ).header()).html();

                    // Text Processing; optional. 
                    tempvar = tempvar.replace('<br>',' ');
                    tempvar = encodeURIComponent(tempvar);
                    // add this to existing array.
                    orderOfData.push(tempvar+'-'+innerOrder[1]);
              });

              // Building row ID list.
              $.each(RowobjectData,function( index, currentElement ) {
                   $.each(currentElement,function( index, innerElement ) {
                        // Index value is the columns of the row, 
                        // so in this case we get the first column data.
                        // Which itself contains a DOM element containing the row
                        // id to export. 
                        //
                        // you could here export the whole row as a JSON.stringify
                        // object.  
                        if(index === 0 ) {
                            innerElement = $(innerElement).filter(".row_id_dom_container_html_element").text();
                            // Save this content value to the array.
                            saveData.push(innerElement);
                        }
                    });
                });

                // In THIS instance the array values should be turned into 
                // strings and used as GET parameters thus:
                // These will be processed by the recieving page 
                var dataString = saveData.join(':');
                var dataOrder = orderOfData.join(':');

                // Finally redirect to the desired destination point. 
                // Alternatively an AJAX call can be made here.
                window.location.href = '/customMap.php?data='+dataString+'&order='+dataOrder;
                return true;
            } // close action. 
         ]}, //close buttons.
     }); // close datatables
 
}); // close document ready.
```